# What is a squashed 3-sphere?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I have found the term "squashed 3-sphere" used in the literature but could not locate a precise definition of it. I suppose it is topologically a 3-sphere with a metric different from the round one. Could anyone tell me what the exact definition is and or give some reference? Thanks!

EDITED: thanks for the comments. Beyond the references mentioned in (the link mentioned in) Semiclassical comment, another example is http://cds.cern.ch/record/375132/files/9812202.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you could point us to a reference. If I wrote that, I'd probably mean something like $\{(x, y, z, w) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (2w)^2 = 1 \}$. That'd be squashed, by a factor of 2, along the $w$ axis.

Comment: Depending on your context, this Physics Stack Exchange question may be relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the references in the comments and elesewhere it seems that the term squashed n-sphere indeed denotes a deformed (not round) metric on the n-sphere but does not have a precise meaning.